# How to insert arabic characters into my informix database through a django project?

Tags: python, django, database, odbc, arabic

I'm currently working on a django project that connects to my infomix database (using the 64-bit ODBC driver) and it works perfectly, the problem is that when I try to insert the data in Arabic language, it doesn't work and I get an odbc error. I tried using 32-bit ODBC and it worked as it should. I was wondering how to get 64-bit odbc to accept the encoding or features of other languages or can I use another approach to connect my project to infomix? as using 32-bit odbc is not an option.
I hope you can help me and thank you in advance.

connecting django project to infomix database so i can insert data in arabic into my database

Comment: maybe you would need to set this variable as follows: `export CLIENT_LOCALE=ar_AE.utf8`

Comment: @BenyaminJafarii have tried it but it didn't work also some characters can be inserted without any problem but some others are causing an error